# ReferenceError on Google Chrome but not on Firefox (Browser Bug?)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, referenceerror

This piece of code

```js
eval(`
    let a = 0;
    function f() {}
    function g() { a; }
    console.log(f);
`);
```

works fine on Firefox 48.0 while causing `Uncaught ReferenceError: f is not defined` on Google Chrome 52.0.2743.116 (64-bit).

It also works fine on Google Chrome if

- `eval` is not used, or
- the code inside `eval` is surround with `{}`, or
- `a` is not referenced in `g`, or
- `let` is changed to `var`, or
- `"use strict"` is added before the code

What's happening here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it's [a novel V8 bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/v8/issues/detail?id=5295)! A more minimal test case is

```
eval(`
    var f;
    let a;
    ()=>a
`);
f;
```

Variable-scoped declarations (which includes top-level function declarations) aren't getting properly hoisted out of non-strict `eval` calls when the call also has a nontrivial lexical declaration.

Answer (score 5):

Tweaking your example you can see what's happening, and while the command is a bit contradictory, it looks like a bug. Define **a** as a function and log it instead of **f**, then have a look at the console. You'll see that a closure was created with **a, f and g**. Since **a** is referenced in g, and f and g should be visible to each other, it makes a bit of sense. But eval works in the global scope. So when you try to access them, you get undefined. It's like this closure cannot be accessed from anywhere.

Try:

```
eval('let a = function(){}; function f() {};function g(){a;};console.dir(a);');
```

You'll see this in the console:

```
<function scope>
    Closure
        a: function()
        f: function f()
        g: function g()
```

All your other cases make the situation clearer, and prevent the issue:

- ***eval is not used:*** the scope mismatch is less obvious,
- ***the code inside eval is surround with {}***: the variables are linked
  through a Block scope.
- ***a is not referenced in g***: no need for a closure if the variables
  aren't linked.
- ***let is changed to var***: var in the global scope is defined in the
  global scope. So no Closure needed
- ***"use strict" is added before the code***: use strict in eval prevents
  variables to be added to the global scope, so again, "easier" to
  handle. No mismatch between having let needed to be linked with global functions.

Answer (score 2):

```
eval(`
    "use strict";
    let a = 0;
    console.log(f);
    function f(){
    }
    function g(){
        a;
    }
`);
```

> Block-scoped declarations (let, const, function, class) not yet supported outside strict mode

Comment: `let` is supported in sloppy mode since Chrome 49.0 according to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let#Browser_compatibility).